# lvcreate + how to set lvcreate with variables when size is in GIGA

Tags: bash, shell-script, lvm

dear all friends

We want to create the `VOLUME_GROUP_NAME`

As

```
lvcreate -n $LV_NAME --size $P_size $VOLUME_GROUP_NAME
```

and the variables are

```
VOLUME_GROUP_NAME=VG_a
LV_NAME=LV_NEW_1
P_size=5  ( is the new partition size in GB )
```

The problem is that is that probably when we set the `$P_size` the default is megabytes and we want in `Giga`

So we change to

```
lvcreate -n $LV_NAME --size $P_size"g" $VOLUME_GROUP_NAME
```

but we get

```
Volume group "VG_a" not found
  Cannot process volume group VG_a
```

So how we can set the `$P_size` in `Giga` ? when using variables

Answer (score 1):

> `Volume group "VG_a" not found Cannot process volume group VG_a`

I don't think your problem is with the size, but with non-existing volume group `VG_a`. Make sure the volume group exists and it's usable (it is possible one of the PVs is missing and that's why `lvcreate` can't find it -- `vgs` output might help, or run `vgscan` to try to scan for the volume group).

The `lvcreate` command itself looks ok, it should work with `5g` (`$P_size"g"`) without problems (with existing volume group).

Comment: either `${P_size}G` or `$P_size"G"` will give expected result.